# Tweepy: How can I get more than 20 tweets from a user?

Tags: twitter, tweepy

According to [their docs](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.3.0/api.html):

```
API.user_timeline([id/user_id/screen_name][, since_id][, max_id][, count][, page])

Returns the 20 most recent statuses posted from the authenticating user or the user specified. It’s also possible to request another user’s timeline via the id parameter.
```

So how can I get more than 20 tweets from a person's timeline? The docs do not show how...Does that user need to be authenticated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `pages` parameter in `API.user_timeline([id/user_id/screen_name][, since_id][, max_id][, count][, page])`. For `page` value 1, you will get a set of latest 20 tweets from the user timeline and then in further iteration, when we increase the value of `page = 2` then the method returns other 20 tweets which are older from the the oldest tweet received from page 1, You can think of this as:

Suppose you have 120 tweets in the account (1st tweet being the oldest and 120th tweet being the latest), then:

> `page = 1` would return (100, 120]
>
> `page = 2` would return (80, 100]
>
> ... and so on

I hope you got the concept of pages now it's time to implement those things.

```
no_of_pages = int(raw_input("Please enter the number of tweets: "))
for i in xrange(no_of_pages):
    API.user_timeline("@anmoluppal366", page = i)
```

Comment: would you know how to do this using Ruby?

Comment: @marriedjane875 have a look: https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/examples/AllTweets.md

Comment: why are you so awesome? @anmol_uppal

Comment: `page` is no longer a valid parameter in this method, check [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html). And, keep in mind that you can only get the most recent 3200 tweets. If you want to get more, other methods are needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the max_id parameter. Something like

```
r0 = api.user_timeline("@donaldtrump") # gives 20 latest tweets
idlast = r0[-1].id # the last id of these 20
r1 = api.user_timeline("@donaldtrump", max_id = idlast) # next 20 tweets older or same age as idlast
```

Comment: max id doesn't work