# Twitter list ID

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I'm using twitter API tweepy and I want to use `api.list_timeline()` function.

It says I must provide either a `list ID` or `slug` and `owner`.

How can I get these information?

Comment: Do you have the list name and Twitter username? these are the `slug` and `owner`. The `list ID` is available from the `api.get_list` function, but you would still need the `slug` and `owner_screen_name`

Answer (score 1):

The id of a twitter list can be found by looking at end end of the URL of the list on twitter web, for example in the url `https://twitter.com/i/lists/1269293736644796416`, **1269293736644796416** would be the id.
To implement it into your code you would simply write:
`api.list_timeline(list_id=1269293736644796416)`

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how can I get more than 20 tweets from list timeline? By default it gets 20 tweets.

Comment: I'm not too sure as I haven't tried it myself but there's a similar thread so have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30423913/11095829